# div ,get css attributes from java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey there i want to change some css attributes from javascript

but i cant access css values for that div

here is what i have in my css file

```
#sidebar {
float: left;
width: 160px;
padding: 25px 10px 0 20px;
}

#sidebar ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
```

here is my html code for that div

```
 <div id="sidebar">
     <%@ include file="some_page.jsp" %>
 </div>
```

here is my javascript code on some click event

```
var element = document.getElementById('sidebar');
alert(element.style.length); //Will alert 0
alert(element.style.width);//Empty alert box
```

i want to change the width attribute , 
can u help me please ?

thank you

Comment: Use firebug and the console.log() instead of alert(), you'll get better messages in the Console tab of firebug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, based on the code from here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html
​

```
var sidebarWidth = getStyle('sidebar','width');

function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
    el = document.getElementById(el);
    return (el.currentStyle)
        ? el.currentStyle[styleProp] 
        : (window.getComputedStyle)
             ? document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
                                    .getPropertyValue(styleProp)
             : 'unknown';
}​
```

---

**EDIT:**

To give perhaps a more readable version of the code, this is closer to the quirksmode version. I had changed it to get rid of the unnecessary variables.

```
var sidebarWidth = getStyle('sidebar','width');

function getStyle(el,styleProp) {
    el = document.getElementById(el);
    var result;
    if(el.currentStyle) {
        result = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        result = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
                                    .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    } else {
        result = 'unknown';
    }
    return result;
}​
```

Comment: This is for getting the computed style of an element when no inline style has been added. To set a style, you either update its inline style attribute with `element.style.width = "100px"`, or you create a stylesheet and append it to the document. Not sure what your exact situation is, but there should be lots of answers on SO that relate.

Comment: ok the new example helped me to write the setStyle method 
for some reason,the methods wont pass the line,getElementById,any ideas?   
function setStyle(elementName,styleProp,styleValue) {  
 alert('HERE SET');  
    var el = document.getElementById(elementName);  
    alert(e1);  
    if(el.currentStyle) { 
        el.currentStyle[styleProp] = styleValue;  
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {   
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).setProperty(styleProp ,styleValue ,'important');  
    } else { 
     alert("nothing to do"); 
    }  
}  
setStyle('sidebar','width' ,'0px');

Comment: @shay - If you're trying to update the style of an element, just set its `style.whatever` property. (By the way, in the code you posted, the second `alert()` was given `e1` instead of `el`. Here's your function: `function setStyle(elementName, styleProp, styleValue) { document.getElementById(elementName).style[styleProp] = styleValue; } setStyle('sidebar', 'width', '0px');​`